# Адаптивная вёрстка на JS: в поисках оптимального подхода

Tags: javascript, html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Как Вы знате, одних медиа-запросов на `CSS` может быть недостаточно для нормальной адаптивной вёрстки, и когда надо менять состав потока и сам поток, приходится использовать `JavaScript`.

Если бы задача просто заключалась в том, чтобы единыжды сформировать поток под размер окна смартфона с предположением того, что потом ширину окна многократно менять *не* будут, технических проблем было бы не так много. Моя же задача в том, чтобы вне зависимости от устройства (смартфон, десктоп или планшет) менялись стили и вёрстка, сколько бы изменений размеров окна не производилось.

Я вижу оптимальный подход в решении этой задачи таким:

1. Делаем базовую вёрстку: всё, что внутри `<body>`, обёртываем в `<noscript>`. Теперь сайт будет отображаться при выключенном Javascript. На этом этапе при влючённом JS у нас будет пустая страница.
2. Заносим все HTML-объекты вместе с атрибутами (включая классы и ID) во внешний файл JS; каждую группу объектов (заголовки, таблицы и прочие составные объекты) делаем значением переменной.
3. Пишем функцию `BodyResize()`, которая при каждом изменении размера окна будет удалять всё внутри `<body>` и выстраивать поток заново.
4. Все стили будут храниться в CSS-файле; как только поток будет выстроен, нужные стили применятся.

Ещё раз повторюсь, что весь этот мазохизм нужен затем, чтобы неограниченное количество раз менять ширину окна, и вне зависимости от того, какая ширина была изначально, отобразится нужный поток (при всём моём уважении к автору, [этот](https://myrusakov.ru/jquery-adaptive.html) подход не решит данной задачи: он лишь единыжды сформирует поток при загрузке страницы. Я пытался модифицировать этот сценарий, чтобы он срабатывал при каждом изменении размера окна, но лишь только перемещением и вставкой объектов (`insertAfter`, `preprendTo` и т. д.) задачу не решить: чтобы каждый таким образом формировать правильный поток для конкретного диапазона ширин, нужно прописать все комбинации *else if* для каждой исходной и окончательной ширины окна).

Итак, вопросы:

1. Какие недостатки у приведённого выше подхода (кроме низкой скорости загрузки)?
2. Какие подходы, лучший чем этот Вы можете предложить (кроме RESS; этот подход реализуем только группой профессионалов)?
3. Приведите пожалуйста 2-3 строчки кода пустой функции JS, которая срабатывает как при первой загрузки страницы, так и при изменении размера окна (я пока могу реализовать только что-то одно).

Comment: _Приведите пожалуйста 2-3 строчки кода пустой функции JS, которая срабатывает как при первой загрузки страницы, так и при изменении размера окна_ - [window.resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize)

Comment: Как альтернативу можно рассмотреть LESS или SASS, [бутстрап](http://getbootstrap.com/) как пример для адаптивной вёрстки. Для адаптивного(абсолютно разного) контента можно использовать разные темплейты которые будут подбираться [JS фреймворками](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620368/change-the-templateurl-of-directive-based-on-screen-resolution-angularjs). Если чесно интересный вопрос, жалко времени нет ответ с примерами накатать

Answer (score 1):

onload, onresize

```
function f(){....}

window.onload = function() {
     window.onresize = f;

     f()
 }
```